# Is there any way to transpose table data in Integrated Timeseries chart of AG Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I want to transpose the table in upper panel and keep the chart intact but don't want to lose editing feature of the table. If I use Pivot integrated chart (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/integrated-charts-api-pivot-chart/) transposition is done but I am not able to edit cells. Here is link and code of Integrated Timeseries chart (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/integrated-charts-time-series/)

[image]